# Failure in running HelloWorld cocos2dx

Tags: android, linux, cocos2d-x

I'm newbie.

Trying to run HelloWorld example comming with cocos2dx (cocos2d-2.0-rc2-x-2.0.1), 
Android SDK 20.0.1, Android NDK r8, on 64bit Linux machine (openSuse 12.1).

When running emulation from Eclipse got following exception:

```
W/dalvikvm(  644): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
E/AndroidRuntime(  644): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 77
E/AndroidRuntime(  644): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No configs match configSpec
E/AndroidRuntime(  644):        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$BaseConfigChooser.chooseConfig(GLSurfaceView.java:863)
E/AndroidRuntime(  644):        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.start(GLSurfaceView.java:1024)
E/AndroidRuntime(  644):        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1401)
E/AndroidRuntime(  644):        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
D/gralloc_goldfish(  644): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

for 2.0, you need to run on a device because the Emulator does not support OpenGL 2.0

for those are interested in how to get OpenGL 2.0 runs on Emulator, here is the link http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/12563

Comment: Actually it's possible, but requires some special configs

Comment: @psousa: yeah, but I guess how to do it will kill most of the people. :P

Comment: @m.ding can you give a reference?

Comment: @m.ding and how do you know it's OpenGL 2.0?

Comment: @m.ding version of OpenGL in emulation environment is dictated by ANDROID SDK/NDK?

Comment: @dimba : coz cocos2d-x 2.0 use openGL2.0. I am not sure about the details, but cocos2d 1.x uses openGL1.0. I guess you are right.